# Shall I Directly set a fragment variable in background service?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

In my `DummyFragment.java` I have a variable, let us say

```
      Public Static String boolean temp = false;
```

In camera `UVCService.java` shall I use the varible with out any `interface` between `fragment` to UVCService?
Let us say in `UVCService.java`

```
      DummyFragment.temp = true;
```

I want the variable to be set in UVCService. But when the app is in background the variable is set to "true" in UVCService, but it is not updated in my activity.

Can anyone help.